# Gaussian Kernel faster than Linear

Tags: svm

I have a Dataset with 580 samples and 7 features. I compared the time between three kernels: Linear, Quadratic and Gaussian and using RandomizedSearchCV as the following:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

paramSVMLinear = {
        'kernel': ['linear'],
        'C': [ii for ii in np.linspace(1,1e7,50000)]
        }

scal = StandardScaler()
X = scal.fit_transform(X)

RandomizedSearchCV(SVC(), paramSVMLinear, n_iter=1, cv=2, scoring='accuracy', verbose=4).fit(X_train,Y_train)

SVC(kernel = 'linear').fit(X_train,Y_train)
SVC(kernel = 'poly',degree=2).fit(X_train,Y_train)
SVC(kernel = 'rbf').fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

The elapsed time in each fit is 187.64 sec, 0.001672 sec, 0.00187 sec, 0.001586 sec. Why the randomized search take so long for 1 iteration and 2 CV? Why the linear kernel take a longer time than RBF? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A plausible reason that linear kernel takes longer is that **data are not linearly separable**, thus it takes longer to fit than a non-linear kernel like RBF.

> The kernel trick avoids the explicit mapping that is needed to get
> linear learning algorithms to learn a nonlinear function or decision
> boundary.
> [..] Some algorithms that depend on arbitrary relationships in the
> native space $X$ would, in fact, have a linear interpretation in a
> different setting: the range space of $\varphi$. The linear
> interpretation gives us insight about the algorithm. Furthermore,
> there is often no need to compute $\varphi$ directly during
> computation, as is the case with **support-vector machines**. Some
> cite this **running time shortcut as the primary benefit**.

(emphasis mine)

References:

1. [Kernel trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method#Mathematics:_the_kernel_trick)

Comment: I see, thanks for the comment!  Why it takes a lot longer on RandomizedSearchCV  (10000x) than just one fit? Theoretically, split the training data in 2, make 2-fold cross-validation and does the fit.

Comment: This has to do with the implementation of [`RandomizedSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html), and how CV and fitting is done. See documentation. Is this time consistent or might be different if ran again?

Comment: Its time consistent. Seems like a bug, I cant see an explanation for this behavior

Comment: If the time taken is consistent, then dive into the implementation of RandomizedSearchCV to see what operations it does. Else if time was not consistent, then it might depend on which random value for C was chosen.

Comment: You can set the `verbose` option to `True` to see what is going on. And here is the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py)

Answer (score 0):

**Not inherently faster:** Gaussian kernels are not inherently faster than linear kernels. The efficiency of a kernel depends on various factors, including the specific problem and implementation.

**Implicit dimensionality reduction:** Gaussian kernels can implicitly perform dimensionality reduction, making them efficient in some cases by mapping data to a higher-dimensional space without explicitly transforming the data.

**Kernel trick:** Gaussian kernels use the kernel trick, which can save computational resources by operating in the feature space without explicitly calculating transformed feature vectors.

**Sparse support vectors:** In some scenarios, Gaussian kernels result in a sparse set of support vectors, leading to faster prediction times during testing.